# customize macro when using ndk-build

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, ndk-build

To my understanding, I can customize a macro with `LOCAL_CFLAGS += -DMY_DEFINITION` in `Android.mk`, but Can I customize a macro when ndk-building projects? Such as:

```
$ ndk-build -DMy_DEFINITION
```

Somewhat like `cmake -DMY_DEFINITION ..`, which makes building configurations more flexible

Comment: You could try using `APP_CFLAGS` for that. I.e. `ndk-build APP_CFLAGS=-DMy_DEFINITION ...`

Comment: `cmake -DMY_DEFINITION` and `LOCAL_CFLAGS += -DMY_DEFINITION` do different things. Do you want to create a define that's visible to your C/C++ code, or to your Android.mk files?

Comment: @Dan Albert wanna creating a define in Android.mk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
ndk-build MY_DEFINITION=1
```

That will be visible from your Android.mk. Can see that it is set by using `$(info)`:

```
$(info MY_DEFINITION=$(MY_DEFINITION))
# Rest of your Android.mk...
```